# Angular Material Autocomplete with Object Code and Description

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular10

I am trying to use a Angular Material Autocomplete with a class. I have Description shown in scroll-dropdown, and want actual value acquired in formValue to be Code.

For some reason everything works well, autocomplete will show all descriptions in scroll, but when I actually select a description value, a Code renders in textbox. It should still be showing the description, but store the Code value in the form. This was working fine when using mat-select dropdown, however transferring to autocomplete is causing some issues.

Is anyone familiar with how to resolve this?

[image]

**Typescript:**

```
 readonly dataSource = DataSource;
 dataSourceFilteredOptions: Observable<Array<BaseParentLookupVm>>;

  private _filterDataSource(value: string): Array<BaseParentLookupVm> {
    const filterValue = value?.toLowerCase() ?? '';
    let data = this.dataSource.filter(option => option.description.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    return data;
  }

  createDataSourceFilteredOptions() {
    this.dataSourceFilteredOptions = this.processBatchForm.get('dataSourceField').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filterDataSource(value))
      );
  } 

 public initializeNewBatchForm(): void {
   this.processBatchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'dataSourceField': [null, [Validators.required]],
  });
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Data Source</mat-label>
    <input 
      type="text"
      placeholder="Select"
      matInput
      formControlName="'dataSourceField'"
      [matAutocomplete]="templateDataSource">  
      <mat-autocomplete 
        #templateDataSource="matAutocomplete"
      >
      <mat-option>Select</mat-option>
      <mat-option 
        *ngFor="let dataSourceItem of dataSourceFilteredOptions | async" 
        [value]="dataSourceItem.code"
      >
        {{dataSourceItem.description}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**Supplemental Code:**

```
export interface BaseParentLookupVm {
  displayOrderId?: number;
  code: string;
  description: string;
}

export const DataSource: Array<BaseParentLookupVm> = [
  { 
    displayCode: '1', 
    code: '1111', 
    description: '1111 Description'
  },
  { 
    displayCode: '2', 
    code: '2222', 
    description: '2222 Description' 
  },
  { 
    displayCode: '3', 
    description: '3333 Description' 
  },
  { 
    displayCode: '4', 
    description: '4444 Description'
  }
];
```

**Resources:**

This answer does straight mapping from value to description, so theirs works.
[Angular Autocomplete Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447818/angular-autocomplete-object)

Trying to update [DisplayWith] using textbox, [Angular mat-autocomplete : How to display the option name and not the value in the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355450/angular-mat-autocomplete-how-to-display-the-option-name-and-not-the-value-in-t)

This answer does not show how to work with textbox, giving another issue [How to display using [displayWith] in AutoComplete Material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234290/how-to-display-using-displaywith-in-autocomplete-material2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using displayWith you have to change your code as:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Data Source</mat-label>
<input 
  type="text"
  placeholder="Select"
  matInput
  formControlName="'dataSourceField'"
  [matAutocomplete]="templateDataSource">  
  <mat-autocomplete #templateDataSource="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option>Select</mat-option>
  <mat-option 
    *ngFor="let dataSourceItem of dataSourceFilteredOptions | async" 
    [value]="dataSourceItem">
    {{dataSourceItem.description}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**TS**

```
myControl = new FormControl();
options = [{
    displayOrderId: 1,
    code: "1111",
    description: "1111 Description"
  },
  {
    displayOrderId: 2,
    code: "2222",
    description: "2222 Description"
  },
  {
    displayOrderId: 3,
    code: "3333",
    description: "3333 Description"
  },
  {
    displayOrderId: 4,
    code: "4444",
    description: "4444 Description"
  }
];
filteredOptions: Observable < any > ;

ngOnInit() {
  this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(""),
    map(value => this._filter(value))
  );
}

private _filter(value: any) {
  let filterValue = '';
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    filterValue = value.description.toLowerCase();
  }

  return this.options.filter(
    option => option.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0
  );
}

displayFn(value: any) {
  return value ? value.description : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just had question, what if there are two strings? how will it differentiate here? for code and description?  if (typeof value === "string") {

Comment: Also, I want  [value]="dataSourceItem" to be code,  not the whole class

Comment: this is close though appreciate it

Comment: maybe this? all this seems kind of messy,  if (this.dataSource.find(x => x.code === filterData)) {
      dataSourceDescription = this.dataSource.find(x => x.code === filterData)?.description;
    } else {
      dataSourceDescription = filterData;
    }     , however similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55268844/15435022

Comment: if you want to use display with you have to pass the entire object, cause the function take the [value].

Comment: I gave points and accepted answer, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks